# How to make a SWT window/shell and all the components on it adjustable?

Tags: user-interface, resize, swt, windowbuilder

So I have created windows/shells with buttons in an application but I want everything to resize when expanded and not to stay in one corner. I have used SWT and window builder to achieve this I used Absolute layout and now when I press full screen it is all in one corner how could I make this aesthetically pleasing so all the buttons and labels expand as well?

Comment: Use [Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Layouts such as `GridLayout` are very flexible and automatically resize controls.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Standard layouts in SWT. Refer [How to position your widgets](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html#positioning-widgets) and [Understanding Layouts](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm).

For Example below is a sample code where I have created 2 labels and 2 text in a Grid Layout which will FILL horizontally when you resize. You can change it according to your needs.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class SampleApplication
{

    protected Shell shell;
    private Text text;
    private Text text_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            SampleApplication window = new SampleApplication();
            window.open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open()
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents()
    {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setSize(450, 224);
        shell.setText("SWT Application");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setText("Name");
        lblNewLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

        text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("ID");
        lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false));

        text_1 = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

    }
}
```